# ClassNotFoundException - how do I register a custom namespace in symfony (2.4.4)

Tags: symfony, autoload, psr-0

I have a new bundle `MyBundle` under
`src/MyVendor/Bundle/MyBundle/`

and in the default controller I wish to use class `MyClass` which resides in namespace called `MyVendor\MyComponent`

which is located under `src/MyVendor/Component/MyComponent/src/MyVendor/MyComponent/MyClass.php`

I've tried to do

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
$myLoader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$myLoader->registerNamespace( 
    'MyVendor\\MyComponent\\', 
    __DIR__.'/../src/MyVendor/Component/MyComponent/src'
);
```

in `app/autoload.php` but I'm still getting the `ClassNotFoundException` error.

Either I'm missing something subtle, or my idea is completely wrong (wrong psr-0 dir structure) or should this be done solely via composer's autoload e.g.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { 
        "MyVendor\\MyComponent\\": 
        "src/MyVendor/Component/MyComponent/src" 
    }
}
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

In either case, I'd appreciate any help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've figured it out:

1. `registerNamespace` should not have trailing `\\` in the namespace
2. I need to add `$myLoad->register();`

so the whole thing looks like

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
$myLoader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$myLoader->registerNamespace( 
    'MyVendor\\MyComponent', 
    __DIR__.'/../src/MyVendor/Component/MyComponent/src'
);
$myLoader->register();
```

I'd still like to see how to do this with the `composer` and `dump-autoload`